# Programmatically add methods to class?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, methods, typedescriptor

I'm dealing with an API, that has a class of million methods, I know what these methods do, they're just proxies to a web-service.

The API internally calls these proxy methods using reflection invoking the appropriate method name (don't ask me why it's done this way).

There are methods in the web-services not implemented by the API, and I need to 'inject' these proxy methods dynamically.

**So my question is**: How can I add methods to an existing class (not extension methods)?

I could do this by [Reflection.Emit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exczf7b9.aspx), but I don't know MSIL.
Anyway I'm mentioning it, because I've made another class that inherits from the same base class as the API does, and implemented the methods there, so maybe there is a way to copy the methods to the API class, because they only call methods of the base class which refers to the same one.

Comment: Why do you need to "inject" them dynamically?  Are you really saying that people add services to your external API and you want to be able to invoke them without a recompile?

Comment: @KirkWoll, the .NET API they provide covers only a part of their web API, I want to add some methods to covert other web parts, but every call goes thru that message that invokes a method in this class by reflection, so I guess that's the only choice, or else I'll have to re-write the entire API, which is much more effort. So yes, I'd like to inject the methods. Furthermore, I will make a function that check my assembly (for attributed classes etc.) and 'registers all the methods' that should be registered. As I said, they are just proxy methods, and it's easy to make a robot that builds them.

Comment: I still don't understand why you want to add methods **dynamically** when you know the *full* API at compile time.  That makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realistically, there's no way you're going to modify an existing class in the way you want. Even using Reflection.Emit, it won't do what you want because the API is calling a specific type, and you can't modify the definition of a type during runtime. What you can do with Reflection.Emit is define a type that inherits from the proxy, but getting the API to load your inherited type will probably prove to be impossible unless they're using a dependency injection framework, which seems unlikely.

The only real way to do this is to go in and modify the bytecode of the dll using decompilation and recompilation. This is how Postsharp does AOP, but imo, I'd never do this for any other reason.

If you have any access to this code or even their libraries, then there is probably a better way around your problem.

Comment: Lemme tell you how the proxy method in the API is called, the API uses reflection to call method X of type X. So you're saying there isn't anyway to add a method? I think it's worth the effort, since that is the only obstacle, I've looked thru the decompiled code of the API. Otherwise I'll have to rewrite their entire API which is already built of zillion classes.

Comment: If you mean add a method to type X, unfortunately, that's not possible in most (all?) statically-typed languages. Otherwise known as monkey-patching in dynamically typed languages like Javascript and Ruby.

Comment: OK. I think I found a way, I'll inherit that proxy class, and I have a way to tell the API to use my proxy class instead, I'm checking it now. Anyway thanks for you input!

Comment: Great! I'm surprised the API is that flexible since it's so oddly designed, but that's good to hear.

Comment: :( Nops... It's a static line in the base method telling the API to use proxy class X. I wish I could mislead the API to use my proxy class that inherits the API proxy class.
It's changing a single `typeof(X)`...

Comment: OOOOPS! I can do it! the line is `mServiceType` = typeof(X)`, I'll change the value of `mServiceType`, which is an instance field. I'm sure this is gonna work!! Will let you know if you are curious.

Comment: Even you're not curious I am here to tell you, that yes that worked. I did have to make some dirty workarounds, but didn't have to use f%ed up things (emit }:P). Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're going to be using reflection as well, save yourself some headache and wrap that logic in Extention Methods (even though you specifically said not).

If you have more information about why Extensions Methods are a bad idea in this case, or why you want to do something that the API developers didn't expose, I might be able to come up with something more useful.

Comment: This is exactly what extension methods were designed for. +1

Comment: No. The API is the one who decides what method to call, and this decision is made by call name (string) so the only choice I see is adding the methods as described in my question, extension methods won't work.

Comment: Negative, the API is what gives you access to features that the developers felt you should be able to access.  Anything else is not an API.